# Copy file with the biggest number in filename via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am looking for command which gives me ability to copy file with the biggest number in name from a folder.

I used this command to copy the newest file from a folder (with some filters which I need):

```
Get-ChildItem "B:\" -Filter '*.exe' | Where Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | Sort LastWriteTime -Descending | Select -First 1 | Copy-Item -Destination 'D:\'
```

Here is folder structure which I have:

```
Release_OSInstaller_2015_CL287638x64_NoDB.exe
Release_OSInstaller_2015_CL287638x64.exe
Release_OSInstaller_2015_CL287337x64_NoDB.exe
Release_OSInstaller_2015_CL287337x64.exe
```

So I need to copy Release_OSInstaller_2015_CL287638x64.exe because name of the file consists the biggest number 287638. Also, I need to make sure that files with "NoDB.exe" parameter won't be copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a PSObject inside your script you can then sort on the number.

The example below is using a regex to get the number and it assumes that the number is prefixed by CL (if not you will need to amend the regex):

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.exe | Where Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | % {
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        No = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
        Name = $_.FullName
    }

} | Sort No -Descending | Select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1 | Copy-Item -Destination 'D:\'
```

Comment: Dave, thank you so so much! I even update your script and now I am able not only copy but execute file with the biggest number in file name


Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\First Name Last Name\Desktop" -Filter *.exe | Where Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | % {
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        No = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
        Name = $_.FullName
    }

} | Sort No -Descending | Select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1 | Invoke-Item

Amazing! Thank you Dave!